# NGINX limit total temporary space usage for client bodies

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am using

```
 client_body_buffer_size 1M;
 client_max_body_size    50M;
 client_body_temp_path /tmp;
```

Because we support uploading large files. However, if 1000 users try uploading at the same same time, this will consume `50*1000=50GB` (approx) of /tmp space, which we consider too much.

How do I ask NGINX to limit the amount of TOTAL space used for client bodies? Lets say we want to limit total /tmp space usage to 2GB.

It would be OK if NGINX returns a 404, 503, 507
, or any other error code, to clients . We can use Retry-After to indicate clients should retry later.

Or is there a way to set up a FCGI callback which can accept or reject a incoming request, before NGINX starts storing the file?

Comment: You cannot check the size of a directory using Nginx settings. You can check the file size through the Content-Length header.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr By the time I read Content-Length , NGINX has already stored the file on disk, right? I wanted to abort before we even start receiving and storing the user uploaded file (if above quota).